# change values in a list without a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

I want to change the values of a list without using a loop or increase the performence

Below is a part of my code.I want to add (1*2),(2*3) ..to a certain range range of the list.Is there any quicker way to do this other than using for loop

```
    k=1
    for j in range(3,100):
        ary[j-1]+=k*(k+1)
        k+=1
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're intending? What's the start to end range supposed to be? Are you looking to create a list, add values to an existing one or change values in an existing one?

Comment: Do you mean "quicker" performance-wise or as "with less lines of code"?

Comment: use recursion to do it without a loop

Comment: change values on existing one

Comment: @LeartS performmence wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive method but isn't be faster than your current code.

I think there isn't better way to modify specific range of values that not change  uniformly like that.

Comment: Using list comprehension is only syntax, performance is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using list comprehension try this:

```
a = [j * (j + 1) for j in xrange(1, 100)]
```

It will return a list: `[(1*2),(2*3),(3*4),(4*5),...]`